# From Proof-of-Stake to Proof-of-work

Tags: proof-of-stake, proof-of-work

Have any (cryptocurrency + blockchain)s switched from proof-of-stake to proof-of-work?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know any cases.

The thing is that if you start the blockchain on PoS mode, **it doesn't have much sense** to change to PoW because:

- The **Tx/s rate will be much lower**.
- It would **force validators to invest money in components with much higher computing capacity** than they would probably have at the time. And at the same time, **it would increase their expenses in terms of electricity**.
- **It will open the door to attacks that are difficult to carry out in PoS** but not in a blockchain in which the miners would still be few and with few resources. We talk about attacks like [the 51% atack](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Majority_attack).

Think about that, a **51% attack is so much harder to succeed in a mature PoS blockchain than on a recently addapted-to PoW blockchain.**

There is one implementation that mixes the two Proofs (i know its not passing fron one to other) but maybe it's useful to you. I'm talking about [HCash](https://h.cash/).

Here i leave you one article that talks about the benefits of mixing PoW + PoS:

https://medium.com/@media_30378/the-advantages-of-the-hybrid-pow-pos-consensus-mechanism-4e9ea4074ac0

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there hasn't been a single case.

Also I do not know rationale for it... doesn't seem to make any sense on the first thought.

Comment: The question does not make sense since cryptos are trying to adapt pos instead of pow

Comment: It does make sense. Indeed, there are advantages and disadvantages for both PO(X).